# I want to access my Uni network from home

Tags: internet, lan

There is a private network in my university which can only be accessed while connected to University Network. Is there any hack by which I can access it from home? Keeping in mind I have very limited acccess on my Uni account

Comment: Don't do that illegally. Get a written permission first, and they you'll get detailed technical procedures. You don't want to get fired from your university and be forbidden of getting any degrees for several years. With permission you might use [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)

Answer (score 1):

In my university, there are specific VPN settings to log into the uni network from outside. You could try contacting your University's network center to find out if they have a similar setup